# XPages CSS and id-attributes

Tags: css, xpages

Normally I can get around the fact xpages hijacks the id-attribute on fields etc by using the x$ jQuery selector...

However, I'm building a sylesheet using the @print media query to make a normal form into a pretty version when printed. I have a scenario, where I have a custom control, have given it an ID of GuidanceArea, and under normal circumstances would be able to reference it in my style sheet with #GuidanceArea, just to simply hide it for example for this scenario.

However this isn't working, I assume because of the ID hijacking? It's not too much of a big deal, as I have workaround where for all elements I don't want to print I just append no-print to the elements styleClass and have .no-print set to display:none in my @media print within the style sheet.

However out of curiosity more than anything, I wondered if there's an easy way to get a hold of an elements ID for use in CSS?

Comment: I do not use your way of styling elements, but I guess the problem is the colon (":") that occurs within the ids created by XPages. As an alternative you could use a CSS selector like `[id$="GuidanceArea"]` to check if an ID ends with a certain string. However, you have to be careful with how you name your elements. Also, this kind of selector is less performant than "#".

Comment: PS: In general I recommend that you use the no-print class.

Comment: Cheers, I'll continue down the road I've started then!

Comment: FYI: In case you are just starting with CSS and/or are not familiar with the available CSS selectors the following page might be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Are you adding the ID to the custom control component itself, or a child component on the custom control?

Comment: It was the custom control itself Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: don't

The longs answer: JSF and XPages manage the id attribute to ensure it is unique on a page. So you don't have actual knowledge what it will be.

The easiest way is to use the class attribute to mark the element of interest, so your selector would be .someclass instead of #someid

But if you absolutely have to: use  an XPages output element to send a piece of computed inline css where you use expression language to obtain the actual id. Browsers or libraries might cough on the : in the id, so your result requires lots of testing. VanillaJS should work.

Comment: Cheers Stephan, as you've mentioned I've gone the class attribute route. Thanks